# Access violations when use free() or delete

Tags: c++, cuda

When in `__global__` Cuda I want to clear a variable from memory permanently an access violation. Sample:

```
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4294967295; i++)
{
    int len = count_numbers(i);
    char * iStr = new char[len]();
    auto iChar = to_str(iStr, i);

    uint p1, p2, p3, p4;
    get_md5(iChar, len, &p1, &p2, &p3, &p4);

    if (myhashp1 == p1 && myhashp2 == p2 && myhashp3 == p3 && myhashp4 == p4)
    {
        printf("good!");
        printf(" i=");
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("\n");
        bool good = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        bool good = false;
    }


    delete (&iChar);
    delete (&iStr);
}
```

> CUDA Memory Checker detected 1 threads caused an access violation.

Comment: How are you allocating it?

Comment: What is `...` ?

Comment: No external links with "full real code". You post a [mcve] as **text** in your question. That's how *you* get help here.

Comment: I added the problem area code just here

Comment: You need to use `delete[]` for things allocated with `new[]`, you're passing the address of `iStr` rather than just `iStr` itself to delete, and without seeing your `to_str` function it's impossible to tell if that delete it correct or not, but I suspect it's the same issue of passing the address of the pointer rather than just the pointer.

Comment: Checked. With delete[] the same thing (

Comment: You're trying to `delete` what was not `new`d. The pointer and the char have **automatic storage duration**. `delete[] iStr;`.

Comment: OK. I think something is wrong here. If I run this code, let's say a cycle of 1000 interactions, then everything works. And if I run all the iterations completely, then the screen goes dead and then the notification Video driver stops responding and has been restored.

Comment: What type does the `to_str()` function return?

Comment: @Galik, char* to_str(char* s, unsigned int n) {}

Comment: " And if I run all the iterations completely, then the screen goes dead and then the notification Video driver stops responding and has been restored. "  That's a WDDM TDR timeout.  You may want to google that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the array version of new:

```
char * iStr = new char[len]();
```

So you need the array version of delete:

```
delete[] iChar;
```

I assume `to_str()` simply returns the same pointer after filling it in so don't delete that, you'll be deleting te same thing twice.